# I have answered 20 questions and have 111 points, but still no badge for [design-patterns]. Why?

Tags: support, tag-badges

I have answered 20 questions on the [design-patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/design-patterns) tag and have 111 points as of now. But still have not received the bronze badge. Can you please have a look?

Answer (score 9):

You have 20 **posts** in that tag, of which [18 are answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1475228+%5Bdesign-patterns%5D+is%3Aa). You need 20 **answers** (and they cannot be community wiki).